# Angular Route redirects to 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my problem : for some reason, on valid links, Angular can't find what I'm looking for and return the 404. Here's the route configuration :

```
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/menus', {templateUrl: 'partials/menus.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/menu/:menuId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html', controller: 'ShowMenuCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/products', {templateUrl: 'partials/products.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/product/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/product.html', controller: 'ShowProductCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/drink/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/product.html', controller: 'ShowProductCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/drinks', {templateUrl: 'partials/drinks.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/order', {templateUrl: 'partials/order.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/404', {templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
```

For example : a link ( such as `<a href="#/menu/{[{menu.id}]}" translate >SEE</a>`) pointing  to /menu/45122245, will work when I'm on /menus/ view, but not on /home/ (and return the 404).

**Same URL is used, same object with same ID, so I don't know what is going on**. I don't know if any other code could help you, let me know what you need :)

Comment: Try adding absolute URLs to your question. There's is a big difference if you are in `/#/menu` or you are in `/menu` when activating a link.

Comment: Same thing, it returns the 404. That's really weird... /product/4578754 (for exemple) should at least display the correct template, right ?

Comment: Can you isolate the bug in a fiddle ot plunkr?

Comment: Well, that seems to work know... And I don't actually know why : I guess the issue came from wrong ID for :productId / :menuId, so it returned the 404...

Comment: Did it work? Did you got a chance to make it fail in a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: 1. Use ng-href instead of href. 2. what is {[{menu.id}]}? that is not an angular expression

Comment: As I use Angular on a Django project, that already use {{ variable }} in its template, I changed Angular default to {[{ variable }]} in order to prevent any conflict.

Answer (score 2):

May be I am too late to reply to this post, but nevertheless I believe the following solution should do the trick,

```
angular.module('moduleName')
..config(['$compileProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($compileProvider, $routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/menus', {templateUrl: 'partials/menus.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/menu/:menuId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html', controller: 'ShowMenuCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/products', {templateUrl: 'partials/products.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/product/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/product.html', controller: 'ShowProductCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/drink/:productId', {templateUrl: 'partials/product.html', controller: 'ShowProductCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/drinks', {templateUrl: 'partials/drinks.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/order', {templateUrl: 'partials/order.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/404', {templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
}])

.run(['$location', function ($location) {
    if ($location.path() === '' && $location.$$absUrl.indexOf('/partials') > -1) {
        $location.path('/home')
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file () unless html5Mode.requireBase is set to false in the html5Mode definition object passed to $locationProvider.html5Mode(). With that, relative urls will always be resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was different.